# Returning multiple identical rows in LISTAGG query

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I'm using Oracle, and want to connect two tables into one select statement (for a report), and we're required to concatenate some of the data from one table into a single row - for which I'm expecting to use LISTAGG.

Simplified version of the problem:

ACCOUNTS table:

| InitialDate | AccountNumber | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1980 | 11111 | 20 |
| 02/01/1980 | 22222 | 30 |
| 03/01/1980 | 33333 | 40 |
| 04/01/1980 | 44444 | 50 |

ACCOUNT_TO_CUST table:

| AccountNumber | CustNo |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 50 |
| 22222 | 51 |
| 22222 | 52 |
| 33333 | 53 |
| 44444 | 51 |
| 44444 | 55 |
| 44444 | 57 |

And what I'm trying to get is something like:

| Account Number | Customers | Initial Date | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 50 | 01/01/1980 | 20 |
| 22222 | 51,52 | 02/01/1980 | 30 |
| 33333 | 53 | 03/01/1980 | 40 |
| 44444 | 51,55,57 | 04/01/1980 | 50 |

However, what I'm actually seeing are duplicate rows, which breaks the reporting tools:

| Account Number | Customers | Initial Date | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 50 | 01/01/1980 | 20 |
| 22222 | 51,52 | 02/01/1980 | 30 |
| 22222 | 51,52 | 02/01/1980 | 30 |

The query I have currently is

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber,
LISTAGG(ac.Customers, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.AccountNumber) 
a.InitialDate, 
a.balance
FROM accounts a, account_to_cust ac
WHERE accounts.AccountNumber = account_to_cust.AccountNumber
Group By a.AccountNumber, a.InitialDate, a.balance
```

I've tried putting a distinct into the initial select, and get an error that the concatenation is too long, and I've tried adding the distinct in the LISTAGG itself, which doesn't seem to work either. How do I eliminate these duplicates?

Comment: Do you - without LISTAGG, just in plain query - also see duplicates? If so, you'll have to get rid of them. Maybe, for example, date values contain time component (hours, minutes) and TRUNC(INITIALDATE) would help. Or, maybe BALANCE should be rounded. Or ...

Comment: I _think_ that the issue is that the way I'm constructing the join could be wrong ? There's one account to multiple customers, so the LISTAGG is probably doing it's thing right and for each instance of the account number it's listing all the customers in the right format - the issue being there's a row for account 22222 and customer 51, then a row for acccount 22222 and customer 52 - so the query is returning two rows, both with 22222 - 51,52 in them to the final result? Does that make sense (and how do I fix it?)

Comment: Your query has some naming issues and a missing comma, but with those corrected [gets the result you want](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c6d2fec32712a546bcd208de0657512). In your real data, do you have multiple values on the same date, but with different times? Or put another way - if you format the `initial_date` column in your output, does that show that they aren't really exact duplicates, [as shown here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37dca0066c8447acde35460405ba9be5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks OK to me (sample data in lines #1 - 16; query begins at line #17):

```
SQL> with
  2  accounts (initialdate, accountnumber, balance) as
  3    (select date '1980-01-01', 11111, 20 from dual union all
  4     select date '1980-01-02', 22222, 30 from dual union all
  5     select date '1980-01-03', 33333, 40 from dual union all
  6     select date '1980-01-04', 44444, 50 from dual
  7    ),
  8  account_to_cust (accountnumber, custno) as
  9    (select 11111,   50 from dual union all
 10     select 22222,   51 from dual union all
 11     select 22222,   52 from dual union all
 12     select 33333,   53 from dual union all
 13     select 44444,   51 from dual union all
 14     select 44444,   55 from dual union all
 15     select 44444,   57 from dual
 16    )
 17  select
 18    a.accountnumber,
 19    a.initialdate,
 20    a.balance,
 21    listagg(b.custno, ', ') within group (order by b.custno) customers
 22  from accounts a join account_to_cust b on b.accountnumber = a.accountnumber
 23  group by a.accountnumber,
 24           a.initialdate,
 25           a.balance
 26  order by a.accountnumber;

ACCOUNTNUMBER INITIALDATE        BALANCE CUSTOMERS
------------- --------------- ---------- ---------------
        11111 01/01/1980              20 50
        22222 02/01/1980              30 51, 52
        33333 03/01/1980              40 53
        44444 04/01/1980              50 51, 55, 57

SQL>
```

As you can see, no duplicates.

Comment: I think my issue might have veen in the listagg order by - I've got the account number, not the customer number which seems to make the difference. Thanks, I best go and re-read about listaaggs....